# Extract the pattern of the time-series dataset through moving average

Tags: time-series, pattern-recognition

I have both time series data and moving average data for the same data-set and the same time interval. I would like to extract the overlapping points. I would like extract those points where the extremum between the current and the last crossing point (intersected point between Moving average and time series) is taken depending on the direction of the trend reveral. I don't have idea whether perform it based on tables (1-Time series table includes temperature and timestamps 2-Moving average table includes only Moving average results of temperature) or perform it based on plot of them in which I have add moving average to time series plot.

Table of Time Series:

```
     ambtemp                  dt
1     -1.14 2007-09-29 00:01:57
2     -1.12 2007-09-29 00:03:57
3     -1.33 2007-09-29 00:05:57
4     -1.44 2007-09-29 00:07:57
5     -1.54 2007-09-29 00:09:57
6     -1.29 2007-09-29 00:11:57
7     -1.42 2007-09-29 00:13:57
8     -1.37 2007-09-29 00:15:57
9     -1.32 2007-09-29 00:17:57
10    -1.37 2007-09-29 00:19:57
11    -1.14 2007-09-29 00:21:57
12    -1.16 2007-09-29 00:23:57
13    -1.08 2007-09-29 00:25:57
14    -1.21 2007-09-29 00:27:57
15    -1.26 2007-09-29 00:29:57
16    -1.50 2007-09-29 00:31:57
17    -1.35 2007-09-29 00:33:57
18    -1.56 2007-09-29 00:35:57
19    -1.60 2007-09-29 00:37:57
20    -1.30 2007-09-29 00:39:57
21    -1.24 2007-09-29 00:41:57
22    -1.24 2007-09-29 00:43:57
23    -1.10 2007-09-29 00:45:57
24    -0.99 2007-09-29 00:47:57
25    -1.04 2007-09-29 00:49:57
26    -0.97 2007-09-29 00:51:57
27    -0.92 2007-09-29 00:53:57
28    -0.70 2007-09-29 00:55:57
29    -0.58 2007-09-29 00:57:57
30    -0.49 2007-09-29 00:59:57
31    -0.54 2007-09-29 01:01:57
32    -0.37 2007-09-29 01:03:57
33    -0.24 2007-09-29 01:05:57
34    -0.34 2007-09-29 01:07:57
35    -0.43 2007-09-29 01:09:57
36    -0.52 2007-09-29 01:11:57
37    -0.16 2007-09-29 01:13:57
38    -0.50 2007-09-29 01:15:57
39    -0.15 2007-09-29 01:17:57
40    -0.04 2007-09-29 01:19:57
41     0.00 2007-09-29 01:21:57
42    -0.08 2007-09-29 01:23:57
43    -0.30 2007-09-29 01:25:57
44    -0.14 2007-09-29 01:27:57
45    -0.06 2007-09-29 01:29:57
46    -0.02 2007-09-29 01:31:57
47    -0.25 2007-09-29 01:33:57
48    -0.33 2007-09-29 01:35:57
49     0.01 2007-09-29 01:37:57
50    -0.28 2007-09-29 01:39:57
51    -0.26 2007-09-29 01:41:57
52    -0.34 2007-09-29 01:43:57
53    -0.43 2007-09-29 01:45:57
54    -0.20 2007-09-29 01:47:57
55     0.19 2007-09-29 01:49:57
56     0.28 2007-09-29 01:51:57
57     0.07 2007-09-29 01:53:57
58    -0.32 2007-09-29 01:55:57
59    -0.20 2007-09-29 01:57:57
60    -0.42 2007-09-29 01:59:57
61    -0.40 2007-09-29 02:01:57
62    -0.54 2007-09-29 02:03:57
63    -0.67 2007-09-29 02:05:57
64    -0.42 2007-09-29 02:07:57
65    -0.57 2007-09-29 02:09:57
66    -0.73 2007-09-29 02:11:57
67    -0.54 2007-09-29 02:13:57
68    -0.70 2007-09-29 02:15:57
69    -0.70 2007-09-29 02:17:57
70    -0.58 2007-09-29 02:19:57
```

Table of Moving average:

```
  [1]      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
 [10]      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
 [19]      NA -1.3250 -1.3300 -1.3360 -1.3245 -1.3020 -1.2770 -1.2610 -1.2360
 [28] -1.2025 -1.1655 -1.1215 -1.0915 -1.0520 -1.0100 -0.9665 -0.9250 -0.8760
 [37] -0.8165 -0.7635 -0.6910 -0.6280 -0.5660 -0.5080 -0.4680 -0.4255 -0.3765
 [46] -0.3290 -0.2955 -0.2770 -0.2475 -0.2370 -0.2230 -0.2215 -0.2310 -0.2240
 [55] -0.1930 -0.1530 -0.1415 -0.1325 -0.1350 -0.1540 -0.1740 -0.1970 -0.2155
 [64] -0.2295 -0.2550 -0.2905 -0.3050 -0.3235 -0.3590 -0.3740 -0.3860 -0.3880
 [73] -0.3695 -0.4045 -0.4450 -0.4900 -0.5125 -0.5215 -0.5515 -0.5825 -0.6140
```

[image: Overlap of time series and moving average for different window size]
Overlap of time series and moving average for different window size

[image: Expected Results for window size of 40]
Expected Results for window size of 40

Comment: I am somewhat unclear on what you are asking. Let me see if I can rephrase; I ask you please to confirm or correct my understanding: (1) You wish to fit a piece-wise linear model to the original time series. (2) You want the turning points of the fitted model -- the points at which consecutive line segments meet -- to capture and reflect, in some sense, the "turning points" of the original series. (3) You propose to identify these "turning points" by comparing the behavior of the original series with that of a derived MA process, identifying "turning points" as points of intersection. Yes?

Comment: If I've got it right -- or if I've got it wrong -- perhaps you could edit your original post to clarify.

Comment: @ArthurSmall, Actually my final purpose is to compare 2 set of time series data with each other. I came up with the idea of comparing the patterns instead of comparing values. So, I want to extract the pattern of each time series and comparing them with each other. I think I can extract the pattern by using moving average and time series. By crossing them and extracting extremum between the current and the last crossing point (crossing point=intersected point between Moving average and time series) the pattern for each time series data can be resulted.

Comment: @aliamidi : have you tried regressing one time series on the other (with some suitable lag structure)? It is not profitable to look for patterns in random data...

Comment: @DeerHunter, No, I haven't try that. would you plz explain "regressing one time series on the other" with relevant tools? Why patterns are not suitable for random data? Are temperature time series data random?

Comment: With package `dyn` : `dyn$lm(timeseries1 ~ lag(timeseries2, -1))`.
Also cross-correlation function: `ccf(timeseries1, timeseries2)`
 Diurnal temperature time series are random due to weather changes and instrumental errors. Re: patterns: the higher the frequency of observations the more changepoints you find. Trend patterns **can** be used for recognition purposes, but at a higher level of analysis.